# Watch HBO on AppleTV without jailbreak

Tags: ios, appletv, airplay

I use my AppleTV for watching Netflix. But now I am thinking about switching to HBO. Apples [press info for the USA](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2013/06/19HBO-GO-WatchESPN-Come-to-Apple-TV.html) and [press info for the Netherlands](https://www.apple.com/nl/pr/library/2013/06/19HBO-GO-WatchESPN-Come-to-Apple-TV.html) both state that HBO should be available for the AppleTV.

There is no HBO icon on my homescreen. How can I watch HBO on my AppleTV?

*I prefer to do this without a jailbreak.*

*I live in the Netherlands, does that matter?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HBO GO (the app which allows you to watch HBO content with an AppleTV) is only available inside the US.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got down voted. This is the correct answer -- the app isn't available if your region for your Apple ID is set to something other than US. Additionally, you need to be a subscriber to HBO via a cable provider to use the HBO GO app. It's not something you can use without paying for HBO on your cable TV plan.

Comment: There was no downvote from my side. Can a 'bypass' this by setting my apple id to `US`? Or do I need some (fast) proxy server to fix this?

Comment: Funny, the press statement is also issued in the Netherlands.

Comment: A VPN to a server based in the US should work and make the Apple TV think it's in the US. That would require additional hardware though (a router that acts as a VPN client to which you'll connect your Apple TV).

Comment: @AndréDaniel you'll also need a subscription to a US cable service with HBO on your bill -- you need to authenticate your HBO subscription before the app will work. It's not like Netflix where you can just subscribe to Netflix in your country but VPN to the US and see the US content.

Answer (score 1):

It is however possible (if of course you are subscribed to the HBO service) to "airplay" the movie from within the iOS "HBO GO" app on your i-device to your apple TV!

Comment: Although not 'perfect', it is an option.